# How to use System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.2.1 in .NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, jwt, .net-4.5

I have project where i want to validate the token from the request. My project's .NETFramework version is **3.5**. I am trying to use the below code in my project and these piece of code, i have used in an another project to validate a token where the .NETFramework version is **4.5.2**.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TokenValidator
{
    public class TokenValidator
    {
        public static bool IsTokenValid(string token, string secretKey)
        {
            string tokenPGID;
            JwtSecurityToken validatedToken;

            try
            {
                validatedToken = ValidateToken(token, secretKey) as JwtSecurityToken;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static SecurityToken ValidateToken(string token, string secretKey)
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
            TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)),
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateActor = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false
            };
            SecurityToken securityToken = new JwtSecurityToken();
            handler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);

            return securityToken;
        }
    }
}
```

But, i am getting below error in my project:

> Error     Could not install package 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
>   5.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Is there any way to validate JWT token in a project of .NETFramework 3.5 means which version of this package should i use to be compatible with .NET 3.5?

Is there any other way to validate a JWT token in .NET 3.5?

Comment: [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version >= 5.0 depend on .NET Framework >= 4.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/5.0.0). Try a lower version, e.g 4.4.

Comment: 4.4 is not working. I have tried to install that package using NuGet

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no Microsoft Official support to generate JWT for .Net 3.5, but you can use a third party library like the one developed by Auth0: https://libraries.io/github/auth0/jwt

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Auth0 lib suggested by @NicoPaez, but it is deprecated:

> Users are advised to switch to JWT.NET which this library was based
> upon as soon as possible.

Was able to easily dump JWT.NET lib into my code, which is old .Net Framework 3.5 stuff.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/JWT

Answer (score -2):

In my project I use netcoreapp3.0, and to install  System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt I did next steps:

1) **Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Version 4.0.4.402070948**

2) [See there a new version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/4.0.4.402070948) and then update the package
**Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Version 5.5.0**
Then the packages **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens** and **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** will avaibles.